# Rewind loop and reuse if number of posts are not a multiple of 4?

Tags: wordpress, loops, slider

How can I acheive this,

I have a slideshow which displays 4 posts at a time and moves a complete block of 4 posts, what the problem I am facing here is I have 9 posts in the slider and its showing a single post in end `4posts -> 4posts -> 1Post` .

What I need to do is rewind the query again if total number of posts is not a multiple of 4, so that in case I have 9 posts in the loop so it will reuse the query again and fill the blank space with the first three posts.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php $slide_thumb_query = new WP_Query('category_name=slideshow&meta_key=_thumbnail_id'); ?>
<?php while ($slide_thumb_query->have_posts()) : $slide_thumb_query->the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'homeslider', true);
        echo $image_url[0];  ?>">
            <img src="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'homeslider-thumb', true); echo $image_url[0];  ?>" title="<?php the_title()?>"/>
    </a><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    <span class="overlay-box"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend solving this with javascript, slide show is build in javascript so it should solve the problem.
Global steps:

1. Count the `<li>` items
2. Determine if it is a 4ish number (use modulo or what ever you want)
3. Copy the first `<li>`'s you need and append them to the end.

Questions ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP_Query's `rewind_posts` method to start over at any time. So when you reach the end of your initial loop, you need to figure out how many more posts you'd like to add, and make some extra loops. `rewind_posts` will not hit the database, so it's not like an additional query or anything. Here are my thoughts in code:

```
$featured_posts = new WP_Query( ... );
while ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ) {
    $featured_posts->the_post();
    // Output your things here
}

// Do we need more posts?
if ( count( $featured_posts->posts ) % 4 > 0 && count( $featured_posts->posts ) > 0 ) {
    $more_to_go = count( $featured_posts->posts ) % 4;

    while ( true ) {
        $featured_posts->rewind_posts();
        while ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $featured_posts->the_post();
            // Keep printing your things here

            $more_to_go--;
            if ( $more_to_go < 1 )
                break 2; // break both while loops
        }
    }
}
```

That's off the top of my head, with multiple loops, so even if your featured posts will contain only one item, it'll just get repeated four times. I didn't test this, but hopefully it'll give you a clue where to dig.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello Kov,

Can you pls elaborate the code you are suggesting, I am a bit confused...

Comment: Ok, so you first output the posts you retrieve. Then if that number of posts is a multiple of four, you enter an infinite while loop, having the `more_to_go` variable tell you how many more posts you need to output. So within that while loop you rewind your featured posts loop and run it again, like the original one, decrementing `more_to_go` with every output post. When `more_to_go` reaches 0, all loops are broken. Questions?